# Trying to embed form into Avada theme wordpress site; getting error: 'Form failed to load. Please try again.'

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm trying to embed code for a form created in another system. This loads just fine in another wordpress site (built with Elementor, not Avada ThemeFusion). This leads me to believe the issue is with the Avada theme. I tried using the code block element and it wont load the form.

I created a new page and embedded the code not using ThemeFusion builder, and instead just dropped the code block in the 'text' field. Still didn't work.

`<div class="tomn-form-embed" data-form-id="J2bsq" data-user-id="yGVig"></div><script async src="//amp.academymortgage.com/formembed/embedform.js"></script>`

I expected the code to render a form and instead got 'Form failed to load. Please try again.'

Comment: wordpress.stackexchange.com is probably a better place to ask this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll head over there.